# Catch a value from a drop down list

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to use PHP to take a value from the drop down list and put it into a PHP variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      <select name="class_form">
        <!--create a drop down list-->
        <option value = "Jive">Jive</option>
        <option value = "Zumba">Zumba</option>
        <option value = "Salsa">Salsa</option>
        <option value = "HipHop">HipHop</option>
        <option value = "Foxtrot">Foxtrot</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" name="submit_button">Select Class</button>
<?php
      //take one of the values from the drop down
      //list and put it into the $class_name variable

      $class_name = $_POST['class_form']; 

      if($_POST["submit_button"])
      {
        echo "class name caught";
        //when the submit_button is pressed the
        //value of the $class_name is echoed
        echo $class_name;
      }
?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button all that happens is the page is reset and the variable is null

Comment: Print_r($_POST)

Comment: You ommited the ``action='...'`` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your form in order to use the action attribute. And you also need to use an input instead of a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- you need to specify the page that will treat your code, for you it's $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] -->
    <form method="POST" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
      <select name="class_form">
        <!--create a drop down list-->
        <option value = "Jive">Jive</option>
        <option value = "Zumba">Zumba</option>
        <option value = "Salsa">Salsa</option>
        <option value = "HipHop">HipHop</option>
        <option value = "Foxtrot">Foxtrot</option>
      </select>
      <!-- <button type="submit" name="submit_button">Select Class</button> -->
      <!-- you need to use an input in order to achieve your goal, not a button -->
      <input type='submit' value='Select Class' name='submit_button'>
<?php
      //take one of the values from the drop down
      //list and put it into the $class_name variable

      $class_name = $_POST['class_form']; 

      if($_POST["submit_button"])
      {
        echo "class name caught";
        //when the submit_button is pressed the
        //value of the $class_name is echoed
        echo $class_name;
      }
?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ensure that your page holding the form will always treat the form, no matter what name your choose for it. You can then change it to `whatever.php` or `stackoverflow.php` and it will still act as is.

[PHP : $_SERVER superglobal variable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 1):

The default method for a form is GET, however you are attempting to capture POST variables. So change your form's method to be POST:

`<form method="POST">`